# Get FileInfo from a path based on Is64Bit bool

Tags: c#, .net, windows

So I've got a `string Path` that represents the path to a file, something like `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` for example.

My app is set to Any CPU and that won't change, but given a `bool Is64Bit` flag, how can I have a method that returns the following:

```
// On 64 bit OS
GetFileInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", Is64Bit: true); // return C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
GetFileInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", false); // return C:\Windows\Syswow64\cmd.exe
GetFileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\file.txt", true); // return C:\Program Files\file.txt
GetFileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\file.txt", false); // return C:\Program Files (x86)\file.txt
```

```
// On 32 bit OS
GetFileInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", true); // return C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
GetFileInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", false); // return C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
GetFileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\file.txt", true); // return C:\Program Files\file.txt
GetFileInfo("C:\\Program Files\\file.txt", false); // return C:\Program Files\file.txt
```

In other words, is there a way to force a path to be redirected to its 32bit counterpart from a 64bit app?

Comment: Why do you want that? Windows goes to great pains to make the the difference transparent to applications. You *shouldn't* have to look into `Syswow64`.

Comment: The `Program Files` folder is a different story. It's *not* as special as System32 and nothing prevents a badly written installer from putting a 32-bit application into `C:\Program Files`. There's no shadowing either so you have to use the absolute path to access any file in either `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)`. Applications shouldn't be storing their data in there either, they should use the `%APPDATA%` or `%LOCALAPPDATA%` folders

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know Windows tries really hard to hide it really well, hence the question :)
I have an app that gives me a simple `string Path` and a `bool Is64Bit` and I need to determine if that path exists based just on that. If `Is64Bit` is `false` and the OS is 64bit then whatever path I've been given represents a path as seen by a 32bit app on a 64 bit OS. And while I could just have a 32bit executable (or even something like PowerShell) just for this, I would prefer to keep it all inside one executable.

Comment: There's no shadowing with  `Program Files` so that application should return the proper path, otherwise whatever it returns is a bad path. Testing existence is trivial too, even if the path is bad:  just use `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` based on that flag.

Comment: Besides, `Any CPU` doesn't mean your program doesn't have an architecture. When it runs, it will match the OS's bitness unless the `Prefer 32-bit` flag is set in the build settings

Comment: You can use the [Environemt.GetSpecialFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1) with the appropriate [SpecialFolderEnum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netcore-3.1), eg `ProgramFiles` or `ProgramFilexX86` to get the relevant absolute folder path

Comment: I know about `Environment.GetSpecialFolder` but that implies I have to parse the string to know if there's anything I should convert, trying not to do that.